# Avoid word wrap (and "...") in long tab titles using ViewPager Tab [landscape]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

How do I avoid word wrap and incomplete tab titles ( like the three '...') in Tabs using ViewPager

See screenshot below:

[image]

**UPDATE**

When I set the following in styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:width">80dp</item>
</style>
```

it **partly** works when **I DO NOT ADD A LOGO** in ActionBarStyle:

`<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">`

[image]

**UPDATE 2 - PROBLEM STILL EXIST WITH LOGO**

This is the result, when I use `ActionBarStyle` to add a logo

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: So you don't want to use singleLine?  maxLine would leave out "..."

Comment: do you have an example on how to set this (through style or code)?

Comment: <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLoadPdf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Load Pdf"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="19dp" />

Comment: remove <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>  Also I'm confused if you want the box larger just make it larger

Comment: removing `<item name="android:singleLine">true</item>` causes the same result as show in screenshot 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the width of your `TabText` widget:

```
<item name="android:width">80dp</item>
```

As you see sometimes 80dp is just enough for your content, but sometimes - it's not. You should avoid using fixed width or height. Instead you can use the [`wrap_content`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#WRAP_CONTENT) (wide or high enough to fit the content) and [`match_parent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT) (match the parent size exactly, possibly leaving a lot of "blank space") values.